# Possible to make a node sticky?

Tags: cytoscape.js

is there any way in cytoscape.js to set the absolute position of a specific node such that it does not pan/zoom with the rest of the graph?

I can set the relative position with nodes.layoutPositions() but the whole scene still pans/zooms.

Disabling pan/zoom for the specific node would be good enough, but is it possible?  Specifying absolute position for the specific node might also be good enough if possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can move your nodes in such a way that they appear sticky whenever you pan.

Store the currently panned position and then on a pan event move your node collection in the opposite direction of the pan the same distance like so:

```
cy.on('pan', () => {
      const newPosition = cy.pan();
      eles.shift({
          x: -(newPosition.x - initialPosition.x),
          y: -(newPosition.y - initialPosition.y)
})
```